# hbase doesn't start because of Master exiting error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I attempting to start hbase0.98.4 in windows 8.
I installed hadoop2.3.0 and zookeeper3.3.6.
I started hadoop :

```
 start-dfs.cmd
 start-yarn.cmd
```

then I started hbase:

```
  start-hbase.cmd
```

but The logs give the reason as:

```
    log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.DRFAS
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "DRFAS".
2016-04-06 20:40:44,018 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.98.4-hadoop1
2016-04-06 20:40:44,018 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Subversion git://acer/usr
/src/hbase -r 890e852ce1c51b71ad180f626b71a2a1009246da
2016-04-06 20:40:44,018 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Compiled by apurtell on M
on Jul 14 18:54:31 PDT 2014
 .
 .
 .
    2016-04-06 20:40:45,018 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hado
op.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClu
sterUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster
.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.ja
va:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMaster
CommandLine.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandL
ine.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLi
ne.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2793)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot co
mmunicate with client version 4
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
        at $Proxy7.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryI
nvocationHandler.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocat
ionHandler.java:62)
        at $Proxy7.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFi
leSystem.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:458)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init>
(HMasterCommandLine.java:258)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClu
sterUtil.java:137)
        ... 7 more

D:\hbase-0.98.4\bin>
```

I only want run a simple java program in eclips with hbase but can't start hbase.

My configuration for my hbase-site.xml is:

```
    <configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
 <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>D/tmp/hbase/tmp</value>
</property>
 </configuration>
```

hbase-env.cmd:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=D:/hdp/java/jdk
  export HBASE_IDENT_STRING=$HOSTNAME
  export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

Comment: paste your hbase-site.xml file

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar what? I added my hbase-site.xml.

Comment: is ur hadoop and zoopkeeper starting?

Comment: only hadoop is starting. without of starting zookeeper, habase doesn't start?

Comment: go to the zookeeper/conf and execute ./zkServer.sh to start the zookeeper and check zookeeper started or not

Comment: It doesn't start. I don't know zoo.cfg is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
<property>

<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>

<value>true</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>

<value>localhost</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>dfs.replication</name>

<value>1</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>

<value>2181</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

<value>/home/kishore/hdfs/zookeeperDir</value>

</property>
</configuration>
```

add java home in hbase-env.sh like  **export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_11**.
edit your hbase-site.xml. add zookeeper data directory. start hadoop then zookeeper and then hbase. let me know if not work

Comment: zookeeper starting, after starting of hbase this error shows: Server IPC version 9 cannot co
mmunicate with client version 4